# Finding discrete entropy via differential entropy

Tags: pr.probability, entropy

In a recent [math.se question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1590790/what-is-the-entropy-correction-term-for-a-multivariate-distribution/1598243#1598243) the following was asked which I have slightly edited.

"
Consider a fixed and given $n$ by $n$ matrix $M$ whose elements are chosen from $\{-1,1\}$. Consider also a random vector $v$ whose elements are chosen from $\{-1,1\}$.

We know that  $H(Mv) = n$ if and only if $M$ is non-singular. Here $H$ is the  Shannon entropy of a discrete random variable  (in bits).

[..]

The differential entropy of a multivariate Gaussian is known to be $\frac{1}{2}\log((2\pi e)^n \det(MM^T)$ bits.

There is a correction  factor one has to apply when going from discrete to continuous entropy (see [Theorem 9.3.1 from Cover and Thomas](https://fenix.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/downloadFile/3779571945128/Differential_Entropy.pdf)).  However, we would need this correction term to somehow deal with the fact that the entropy is constant as long as $\det(M)>0$. That is it makes no difference to the entropy how small or large the determinant is as long as it is not zero.

> What is the correction term that deals with this seeming
>   contradiction?

"

A user called leonbloy gave an answer that he/she admitted was not rigorous. I copy it below very slightly edited.

"

We get that the entropy of a discrete (lattice) distribution with "cell size" $\Delta$ is related to the differential entropy of the continuous distribution that approximates it by

$$ H_Y \to h_Z -\log \Delta$$

Now, it's a known result in multivariate analysis that the change in volume induced by a transformation $(s_1, \cdots s_n)=g(t_1, \cdots t_n)$ is measured by the Jacobian. In particular, if the transformation is linear $s =A t$ then the Jacobian is the determinant of the matrix: $J=|A|$.

In our case, we have $y=Mv$. The cells in $v$ space ($v_i \in \{-1,1\}$) have size $2^n$. Hence the cells in $y$ space have size $|M| \, 2^n$. Further, the differential entropy of a Gaussian with covariance $\Sigma=M M^t$ is $\frac{1}{2} \log[(2\pi e)^{n}|\Sigma|]= \frac{n}{2} \log(2\pi e)+\log |M|$

Then, assuming that CLT applies and that $|M|\ne 0$:

$$ H_Y \to \frac{n}{2} \log(2\pi e)+\log |M| -\log (|M| \, 2^n)= \frac{n}{2} \log(\pi e/2)  $$

Hence, the entropy is independent of $|M|$, as it should be.

"

This is intriguing because it gives approximately $1.047n$ instead of $n$.  This got me wondering:

> Can this line of argument be made both reasonably rigorous and be made to give the correct answer?  That is, is it possible to get the correct entropy of $n$ for the discrete entropy $H(Mv)$ by applying Theorem 9.3.1 from Cover and Thomas in this multivariate case?

Comment: strange, a very similar question was asked by another user (and now deleted): http://mathoverflow.net/questions/227434/what-is-the-entropy-correction-term-for-a-multivariate-distribution?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Not so strange! Is that user the author of the question my question points to and quotes? If so, I assume they deleted the question here when they got the math.se answer (although I can't see the question you are pointing to).

Answer (score 1):

A believe that a different way to go from differential entropy to discrete entropy is the following formula.

Let $h(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ be the differential entropy of some random $n$-tuple $X_1,\dots,X_n$ and $H(Y_1,\dots,Y_n)$ be the discrete entropy; we require that $Y_1,\dots,Y_n$ be real-valued.  In other words, if $p$ is the joint density of $X_1,\dots,X_n$ then $$h= -\int p(x_1,\dots,x_n) \log p(x_1,\dots,x_n ) dx_1\dots dx_n$$ and $$H = -\sum_{\vec{v}} Prob( (Y_1,\dots,Y_n)=\vec{v}) \log \left(Prob( (Y_1,\dots,Y_n)=\vec{v})\right),$$ where the sum is taken over all vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

The formula is:
$$ 
H(Y_1,\dots,Y_n) = \lim_{t\to 0} h(Y_1 + tG_1,\dots,Y_n+tG_n) - n\log(t)
$$
where $G_1,\dots,G_n$ are $n$ centered variance $1$ Gaussian random variables which are independent of each other and of $(Y_1,\dots,Y_n)$.

This formula explains why despite the fact that differential entropy changes when one applies a one-to-one function to $Y_1,\dots,Y_n$, the discrete entropy does not.  Indeed if you set $Y_j' = F_j(Y_1,\dots,Y_n)$, then the RHS of the formula will involve a term which is (roughly) $\log \det \left(\left( \partial_i F_j\right)_{ij} \right)$, which disappears in the limit $t\to 0$ being negligible compared to $n\log t$.

(I am adding a few more details that we requested in the comments).

Take the case $n=1$ for simplicity.  Then the law of $Y=Y_1$ has the form $\sum \alpha_j \delta_{x_j}$ with $\alpha_j\geq 0$, $\sum \alpha_j =1$, and $\delta_x$ denoting the point mass at $x$.  Thus $H(Y)=-\sum \alpha_j \log \alpha_j$.

The law of $Y+tG$ is the convolution of the law of $Y$ and a Gaussian of variance $t^2$ centered at zero and so has density
$$
p_t(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \sum_j \alpha_j  t^{-1} \exp( -(x-x_j)^2/t^2)
$$

Let us now compute $h(Y+tG) = - \int p_t(x) \log p_t(x) dx$:

$$-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int \sum_j \alpha_j \frac{e^{ - \frac{(x-x_j)^2}{t^2} }}{t} \left[-\log t + \log \left(\sum \alpha_k e^{ - \frac{(x-x_k)^2}{t^2} }\right)\right]dx.  $$

Noting that $\int \frac{1}{t} e^{ - \frac{(x-x_j)^2}{t^2} }=\sqrt{2\pi}$ the first term in the sum inside $[...]$ gives us $\sum \alpha_j \log t = \log t$.  The second term is
$$-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int \sum_j \alpha_j \frac{e^{ - \frac{(x-x_j)^2}{t^2} }}{t} \log \left(\sum \alpha_k e^{ - \frac{(x-x_k)^2}{t^2} }\right)dx,$$
which because $-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int \sum_j \alpha_j \frac{e^{ - \frac{(x-x_j)^2}{t^2} }}{t}$ converges weakly to $\sum \alpha_j \delta_{x_j}$ gives us precisely $-\sum \alpha_j \log \alpha_j$ (notice that $k=j$ gets forced as well).

Thus $h(Y+tG) -\log t \to H(Y)$.

The multi-dimensional case is essentially the same.

Comment: Would you mind spelling out a little more what you get in the end? In particular, do you get the correct discrete entropy of $n$ this way?

Comment: Thank you but I am not clear on some details. As a first trivial question, doesn't $\log{t}\to -\infty$ as $t$ tends to $0$?  How do you get the entropy of $n$ from the RHS?

Comment: Thank you this 1d analysis.  The 1d case is clear and I was in fact happy with it before. I would be very grateful if you could show how you can apply the same reasoning to the multidimensional $Mv$.  Part of my confusion is what the approach would give if $M$ had fewer rows than columns. This presumably would then depend crucially on the entries in $M$.  But even understanding the $n$ by $n$ case would be a great start.

Comment: I think the proof of the formula relating differential and discrete entropy in the multi-dimensional case is exactly the same -- in fact the only change needed in the argument is the replacement integration with respect to $dx$ by integration with respect to $dx_1 ... dx_n$ (the extra factor of $n$ in front of $\log t$ comes from the joint variance of $G_1,\dots,G_n$).  To see the behavior when you apply your matrix $M$, just use the formula to compute $h((\sum_{i} M_{ij} Y_i)_j )$.